# TypeError with uuid and web3-eth-accounts

Tags: ethers.js

I'm encountering a persistent issue while working on a TypeScript project that **involves web3-eth-accounts** and **uuid libraries**. The core of the problem is a TypeError that occurs when trying to assign to a **read-only property 'name' of a function within the uuid library**, specifically at **v35.js**. This issue seems to stem from a conflict or incompatibility between the version of uuid used by web3-eth-accounts and other dependencies in my project. My environment is set up with **TypeScript version 5.3.3**, **Node.js v18.19.0**, and I've included various other libraries as outlined in my package.json. Despite attempting solutions like incorporating 'regenerator-runtime/runtime' to address async function handling, the problem persists.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share a piece of code that causes that error?